# subscribe with google, how to retrive expiration's date from SubscriptionToken

Tags: android-inapp-purchase

When a user registers with google for our services, the following information is saved in the DB: Key SubscriptionToken and username.

we don't know the expiration's date of the subscription.
So I want to create a batch in c# that every night extract the expiration date for each user registered with google. I found this is the api to invoke

click the [link](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get?hl=it&apix_params=%7B%22packageName%22%3A%22it.ilsole24ore.android%22%2C%22productId%22%3A%22swg_24plus_mensile%22%2C%22token%22%3A%22gdimoifcipoiglnjpolbdhim.AO-J1OwXig6lW_nt99VUlRwkclp_egoplubHf1uRIjCvPmzPqsl7tVD-XYqjlVtpHYk6nqg1SSWfTr-7PBJ_h1RJeJPUtZa0HgpAKOw02dgG5fEUV_nTvMg%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22ya29.c.b0Aaekm1JpYozLdYJ3PlWQIbm9xy64IBOou_2e3ZINpVqAkLiwXNqaMeVLLcJifrSR0-uSidjjLksaEGPCHoxzP2HwL8rg9-gcXJxzotfTBHSpU0osd7Y_S82-Hco1TchALkDjJWl8uHkAEmDUhVo2yGyxL7mpRkz74i7NdNu4D_yh-qgjhClYQD7Nv31aZZVPB742NmNXvx3imeDuFrjDcWGGPT9GczqbyXMF6rY0Sf73AsfHxdiC9wvh9K4xp85Pss347vA3RcyAQxYcLR8yLvvJoiyG9rFe44wfPrGG_mTYM7Th_kF-LpbnSpaMnOFcpogTqrgAL337PW433OeFokkXUyUQx8vMVr3U6IuJ0F3t_dFbibsyVzR-wIsZWbfdszRVs2-i65qVjrsJw4tsdxiS-l1c8yVi1ZoYWaUb773j9wR3xeRo_f-O3vb1vhqw_uBS4MbaW3Oxy6t-ynyoZ7pww4982_3ay3QzOxOJUcnrZbseYYZg2QFaxl2gVpQ_xaISpwz1pfchI5sS5Qp00if8iVmVwMlqnroSf21yfk7u6shamnV7JqjjrVzFF7Sb2-e2VWQdo_d-W3Ykzs4ef341o5soqd9g9cIvJwX8u8YXFlz1l51R0gMeaOQW3kSmWot-Fjqk8q35qlJXQmmJJB1d317yk0X8ernYaOVQs4spW4sazWX3ixsOV91sqcy8fkIrQMu8qY0fM4olkYaVv0p_9dgY1qh4Sxw90am8eIkx5M3xXhp91_bbwBJc8ryu8seXXcjF8sqgiYywy_o1Xns_Vpiv2aw7tUwpzkX3Bmsr75dpFSdlRRn_cZw9619x0y0XcuoB9nZIkq4t72SZfZbSv2fJhlXhR6YWdwqfpR0qwqI3Q9hqfnuqSvmQ37c8VrYd3FwZobbVUhoQ3UFdz59uZdOvWhFi31xR3ijv8a73zxjIkUpkJnt27w7Uxx_4cugzgatzhZgbBjUjc7hO9lX9BVWm5valaZQSfjdt0jrjtR0earQSqp3%22%7D#authorization-scopes) for accessing it.

with this code i create a valid access_token:

```
string getAccessToken()
{
    scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher";
    var _pathJson = @"C:\temp\abiding-ripple-277822-c95186b1968a.json";
    var json = File.ReadAllText(_pathJson);
    var cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonalServiceAccountCred>(json);
    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.client_email)
        {Scopes = new[] {scope}}.FromPrivateKey(cr.private_key));
    var accessToken = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;
    return accessToken;
}
```

but in the api test page i get this error 403 forbidden:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
        "domain": "androidpublisher",
        "reason": "projectNotLinked"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

what do i have to do to link the project in the Google Play Developer Console?